# 0 not an [int] in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, integer, zero

My understanding is that (mathematically) 0 is an Int. And yet

```
if (0 -as [int]){"Int"}else{"Not"}
```

returns `Not`, at least for me in PS 2.0.

Is this a bug in v2, or am I misunderstanding things? 
I have worked around the issue by testing for `-as [int] -and -ne 0`, but that is rather kludgy feeling, so I am hoping I am missing something here and there is a better answer.

FYI, I am specifically dealing with a seed computer name that needs an initial index added or a last computer name that needs an index incremented. The seed looks like **Lab 1-**, and the initial index could be 0 or could be 1 depending on the situation. I had been just testing for the last character to be `[int]`, knowing that - would not be an int. But when the first computer was **Lab 1-00** because the initial index was 0, I also get not `[int]` and things get ugly, with the next computer being **Lab 1-0000**.
Again, the additional conditional is working, just wondering if I am misunderstanding in my expectation that 0 is an `[int]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IF` test is performed by invoking whatever expression is in side the parens, and then evaluating the result as `[bool]`.

```
0 -as [int]
```

returns 0.  When an [int] is evaluated as [bool] (true/false) 0 is $false, so the test always fails.

From the description of the problem, it sounds like you might actually be testing a string instead of an [int].

```
  if ($var -as [int] -is [int]) {"Int"} else {"Not"}
```

Should perform that test without throwing an exception.

Comment: Brilliant! As solution and education. And of course you are correct, I am testing a string, and if it can be an int, then I increment the resulting int, otherwise I use my initial index value to start the sequence.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `0` is of type `[int]`.  You can see this for yourself using the [`GetType` method](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/scriptcenter/en-US/7dcc1ce1-aeb9-471c-87ca-9b87af5db699/gettype-in-powershell):

```powershell
PS > (0).GetType()    
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                  
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType          


PS >
```

The problem is that you are using the wrong operator.  You use `-is` to test type, not `-as`:

```powershell
PS > 0 -is [int]
True
PS > if (0 -is [int]) {"Int"} else {"Not"}
Int
PS >
```

Answer (score 5):

`0 -as [int]` simply means *cast 0 as an int*. The result of the expression is still `0`, which implicitly converts to `false`.

Instead you want to use `0 -is [int]`, which means `is 0 an int` and would evaluate to `true`.

Further reading: [`get-help about_Type_Operators`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847763.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Per your comments below, here is an example of how you might evaluate if the final character can be converted to an int *without* throwing an exception:

```ps
function CheckLastChar($string){
    $var = 0
    $string -match ".$" | Out-Null

    if ([System.Int32]::TryParse($matches[0], [ref]$var)) {
        "It's an int!"
    }
    else {
        "It's NOT an int!"
    }
}
```

```
PS C:\> CheckLastChar("Lab 1-")
It's NOT an int!

PS C:\> CheckLastChar("Lab 1-000")
It's an int!
```

Although, I have to say [mjolinor's `-as [int] -is [int]` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30009420/1029145) is much nicer.

Comment: Hmm, so how to I address the situation where the last character is going to be **-**, when -is will throw an error because it can't be cast to an Int? My understanding of -as was it would take anything and return true if it could be cast to Int, and false if not, rather than an error like -is does. Is the best approach to use -is and a try catch?

Comment: `-as` attempts to convert the input object to the specified type. If it succeeds, it returns the converted object. If it fails, it simply doesn't return anything. `-is` will return `true` or `false` if the input object is or isn't of the specified .Net type, respectively; it shouldn't (as far as I know) return an error. Can you show us some code with your specific approach to the problem?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't describe that right. **"-" -is [int]** returns false as expected. My issue is I am taking the last 2 characters off a string which could be **Lab_1-** or **Lab_1-00** or **Lab_1-09**, etc. And **"0" -is [int]** returns false too, for obvious reasons. So the question should really be, given a single character string, is there a way to see if it can be cast to an integer, without needing to catch an exception when it's a letter or symbol?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Yes, you could do an explicit cast like `[int]"-"` and catch the exception if you wanted. Or if you really really don't want to do that, you could use [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx), like so: `[System.Int32]::TryParse("-", [ref]$var)`. You would have to declare and initialize `$var` beforehand, of course.